Double or triple induction proof
I have this equation:
$$N_k(\left| V \right|,d) = 
\begin{cases}
    \begin{aligned}
       &1, & &\text{if } \left|V\right|= k \\
    \end{aligned}\\
    \begin{aligned}
       & 1+ \left|V\right| - k  + \sum_{i=d}^{k-2} N_k\left(\left|V\right|-1,i\right) , & &\text{if }  \left|V\right|>k
    \end{aligned}
\end{cases}
\label{Equation 1}
$$
where $\left| V \right| \geq k, \quad  k \geq 2 \quad \text{and} \quad 0 \leq d \leq k-1$.
I am trying to prove that
$$
\begin{equation}
N_k(\left| V \right|,0) = {\left| V \right| \choose k}
\label{Equation 2}
\end{equation}
$$
While trying to prove it, it seems that I had to use $N_k(\left| V \right|,d)$. Thus, I tried to prove
$$
\begin{equation}
N_k(\left| V \right|,d) = {\left| V \right|-d \choose k-d}
\label{Equation 3}
\end{equation}
$$
and then I would just substitute $d=0$ to conclude the proof.
I am unsure how the proof should be completed. Is this a triple induction? If yes, what are the steps I should follow? I managed to prove that the equality holds for $\left| V \right| \geq k$, assuming that $k$ and $d$ are constants. This was done as follows:
Base case: Let $\left| V \right| = k$. Then $N_k(k,d)=1$ and ${k-d \choose k-d} = 1$
Assume that it is true for $\left| V \right| = n > k$.
Prove for $\left| V \right| = n+1$.
$$
N_k(n+1,d) = 2+n-k + \sum_{i=d}^{k-2} {n-i \choose k-i}.
$$
Using Hockey-stick identity: $\sum_{j=0}^{n-r} {r+j \choose j} = {n+1 \choose n-r}$ it is easy to verify that
$$
N_k(n+1,d) = {n+1-d \choose k-d}
$$
thus proving the identity $\forall \left|V\right|\geq k$ where $k$ and $d$ are constants.
To complete the proof, should I do the same for $k$ and $d$? i.e. for $k$ keep $\left|V\right|$ and $d$ constant and for $d$ keep $k$ and $\left|V\right|$ constant? If that is the case, I tried it but couldn't manage to prove it. Any tips? Thank you in advance.
